# To show that $\mathbb{Q}(c)=\mathbb{Q}(d)$

Tags: field-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $c= \sqrt[4]{5}+\sqrt{5}$ and $d=\sqrt[4]{5}$
How can show that $\mathbb{Q}(c)=\mathbb{Q}(d)$?

I only have some idea about write $c=d+\sqrt{5}$ and do not know what I need to do for the next step.

Then, to find $[\mathbb{Q}(c):\mathbb{Q}]$ and the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Even I do not know how to show  for this question $[\mathbb{Q}(d):\mathbb{Q}]$ instead of $[\mathbb{Q}(c):\mathbb{Q}]$ since $\mathbb{Q}(c)=\mathbb{Q}(d)$.
And, I know that the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(d)$ is $(1,\sqrt[4]{5},(\sqrt[4]{5})^2,(\sqrt[4]{5})^3)$. Hence, the degree of $[\mathbb{Q}(d):\mathbb{Q}]$  should be $4$.

To find the minimal polynomial of a over $\mathbb{Q}$, I end up with $x^4-x^2=0$ and in this case, it has not prime, therefore cannot apply Eisenstein's test.

Comment: Please slow down and read the answers to your two related questions prior to this one, within the hour.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show containment both directions.  Showing $\mathbb{Q}(c)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(d)$ should be completely straightforward, since $c = d^2 + d$

For the other direction 
\begin{align*}
c&= \sqrt[4]{5}+\sqrt{5} \\
c - \sqrt{5} &= \sqrt[4]{5} \\
c^2 - 2c \sqrt{5} + 5 &= \sqrt{5}\\
c^2 +5 &= (2c+1) \sqrt{5} \\
\frac{c^2+5}{2c+1} &= \sqrt{5} 
\end{align*}
So we can conclude 
$$
c - \frac{c^2+5}{2c+1}  = d
$$
and hence $\mathbb{Q}(d)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(c)$

Comment: Umm, I think you got your inclusions backwards: $c=d^2+d$ means that $c\in\Bbb Q(d)$, and therefore $\Bbb Q(c)\subseteq\Bbb Q(d)$.

Comment: Ugh.  Careless of me.  Thank you!